# How to append to a large XML (file) without loading entire content with PHP

Tags: php, xml, file, append

I made an auto excel to MySQL convertor module to build a self-directory website based on PHP. but i have a serious problem in auto updating it's sitemaps.

converting job continues in whole of a day and google's crawler may fetch sitemap files any time. so i manage to update sitemap's XML files every time a successful entry was converted but updating a large XML file with DOM or simpleXML for every conversion has a heavy cost because all data loaded to RAM first and wrote to file again!

i decided to use "file_put_contents" for speedup like this:

```
file_put_contents($xmlFile, $currentData, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

but problem is every file ended by `</urlset>` and removing the last line require to use `fopen()` and `fseek` that has the same problem, loading entire file!

is there any possible way to modify last line of a file without loading entire content's to RAM or another way to append a new tag to a XML file without loading entire tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fseek()` does **not** require to read the whole file. Just seek to the end, search for the next line break in reverse order and delete the last line.

However, why not using a flattened format? Like:

```
/sub1/page1
/sub1/page2
/sub1/sub2/page1
```

IMO this looks less hackish if you want to append to the file.

Comment: thanx for your information, I used flattened format in url like /language/page/action/params but the number of links are too much (about 500k or higher) and google may not recognize all of them.

Comment: what is the best way to remove last line of a large file by the way? (technical)